# How can I check if a div has a certain class using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

```
if (await page.$("has-cart")) {

const page2 = await browser.newPage();        
await page2.goto('https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout');       
await page2.bringToFront();
}

else console.log('not found');
```

this is supposed to check if the DOM has the class "has-cart" in it then do the function but it isn't working. Plz give suggestions if possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed a dot inside your selector `page.$(".has-cart")` should work.
With `page.$('has-cart)` you would match elements with this name ->

```
<has-cart>..</has-cart>
```

With `.has-cart` you get any element wich contain this class

```
<div class="has-cart">...</div>
```